# Waiting for document-based window to finish initialization

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsdocument

In my document-based application, I need controllers tied to the document controller to work with documents once they've been opened. Unfortunately, `-readFromURL: ofType: error:` fires before these controllers have been initialized and `-windowControllerDidLoadNib:` fires before the document has even been opened, meaning that I have no chance to pass the opened document to these controllers. What's a nice clean way of getting around this problem?

Comment: hmmm, might it be possible to show the code that ends up calling "`readFromURL:ofType:error:`"?  I want to see if there's a way to call it *after* your window is fully instantiated.

Comment: That method is a standard NSDocument method that is called when opening a document from the standard Open dialog, double-clicking the document in the Finder, or dragging the document onto the application icon.

Comment: "`readFromURL:ofType:error:`" is called after you instantiate (create) your custom NSDocument subclass but before the window is loaded/displayed, right?